# The ribbon control of Delphi 2010 has footer content in the application menu?

Tags: delphi, controls, vcl, ribbon

I'd like to put some buttons in the footer content like the image below.

[image]
<sub>(source: [telerik.com](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/images/RadRibbonBar-Features-ApplicationMenu-070.png))</sub>

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - just add an item to TRibbonApplicationMenuBar.OptionItems.